# Return min and max values of DATETIME2(2) on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In one of my views, I want to return two extra columns `ValidFrom` and `ValidTill`. Depending on, if a `LEFT JOIN` finds something, I want to return that value, or the min/max values for my used data type, which is `DATETIME2(2)`.

Right now, I'm using this code:

```
SELECT
  ISNULL(h.Arrival, CAST('0001-01-01 00:00:00.00' AS DATETIME2(2))) AS ValidFrom,
  ISNULL(h.Departure, CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59.99' AS DATETIME2(2))) AS ValidTill
FROM MyTable m
LEFT JOIN MyOtherTable h ON m.ID = h.ID
```

Is there a better way to get the min and max values? I don't like the current, hard-coded version.

Comment: `NULL`, to me, would seem like the *correct* value here. `ValidTill` having a value of `NULL` would mean it is the *"current"* value and has no end validity date at this time. I assume, as well, that `ValidFrom` having a value of `NULL` means that it has always been valid.

Comment: Also, using a value like `9999-12-31 23:59:59.99` and `0001-01-01 00:00:00.00` will likely cause you problems at some point when you try to apply date logic, and end up with something like `DATEADD(DAY, 1,'9999-12-31 23:59:59.99')`.

Comment: As SQL Server doesn't support `infinity` you have to hard-code (or keep NULLs)

Comment: You can safely remove the CAST as ISNULL will convert the second parameter to the datatype of first one

Comment: @Larnu I already considered to leave them as null. But I want to join to that table with a `AND a.Checkdate BETWEEN b.ValidFrom AND b.ValidTill`, and I think, that this woudln't work with NULL values. There can be a valid constellation, where `ValidFrom` is set, but `ValidTill` isn't.

Comment: Considering you have time portions of your values, *don't* use `BETWEEN` @AndréReichelt , it probably won't always give you the results you're after (`2019-11-13 00:00:00.01` isn't between `20191101` and `20191113` for example). Use `>=` and `<` logic. Then you can easily implement `IS NULL` logic as well.

Comment: The answer to your original question is "no", by the way. There are no T-SQL functions capable of giving the minimum and maximum, in the way that `DateTime.MinValue` and `DateTime.MaxValue` in .NET do (you could, of course, make CLR functions for the same, but that's horrible overkill). In fact, T-SQL's lack of actual typed literals for these values mean that converting from characters is unavoidable. Any attempt to get clever at this will typically result in expressions that don't optimize.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the clarification. That, indeed, is rather unfortunate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to example on my comments, as this won't fit/display well in another, but I'll quote them below, in case they are ever removed. My initial response

> `NULL`, to me, would seem like the correct value here. `ValidTill` having a value of `NULL` would mean it is the "current" value and has no end validity date at this time. I assume, as well, that `ValidFrom` having a value of `NULL` means that it has always been valid.

And then my reply in regards to using `BETWEEN`:

> Considering you have time portions of your values, *don't* use `BETWEEN` @AndréReichelt , it probably won't always give you the results you're after (`2019-11-13 00:00:00.01` isn't between `20191101` and `20191113` for example). Use `>=` and `<` logic. Then you can easily implement `IS NULL` logic as well.

This would mean that for your clause `a.Checkdate BETWEEN b.ValidFrom AND b.ValidTill` you would have a clause like this:

```
WHERE a.Checkdate >= b.ValidFrom
  AND a.CheckDate < b.ValidTill
```

This is assuming that `ValidTill` is the moment after the validity expires. For example something valid all day on `2019-11-13` would have the values `2019-11-13 00:00:00.00` and `2019-11-14 00:00:00.00` for ``ValidFrom`and`ValidTill` respectively.

To then turn the above to cater for `NULL` you would do the below:

```
WHERE (a.Checkdate >= b.ValidFrom OR b.ValidFrom IS NULL)
  AND (a.CheckDate < b.ValidTill OR B.ValidTill IS NULL)
```